# How can I make the child fragment visible when a condition is met in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

The objective is to have a picture appear in the bottom fragment after the user successfully logs into the top fragment. So far everything I have tried has resulted in the app crashing. I'd appreciate any help.

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_fragment, container, false);

    loginButton = view.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    userName = view.findViewById(R.id.userName);
    passWord = view.findViewById((R.id.passWord));

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if(userName.getText().toString().equals("test") &&
                passWord.getText().toString().equals("test")) {
                            Toast.makeText(requireActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    "Success! Logging In...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(requireActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Failed Login Attempt",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is really simple to solve. You just have to follow my example down below.

This might help. This is how you can set an ImageView to visible.

```
toolbar.setOnClickListener(v ->
    {
        if(userName.getText().toString().equals("test") &&
                passWord.getText().toString().equals("test")) {
            Toast.makeText(requireActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    "Success! Logging In...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            ImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Add this line of code inside your condition.
        }else
            Toast.makeText(requireActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Failed Login Attempt",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    });
```

Set this code inside your condition. I hope this might solve your problem and I'm really happy to help. Thank you and Happy Coding.